# Iterate over each k-subset such that each element is equally often selected during iteration

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

Let's say we have a set with `n` elements. I want to iterate efficiently over all subsets with `k` elements, such that during iteration, the elements are selected roughly equally.

---

### Example

We have 7 elements: `[a,b,c,d,e,f,g]` and we want all 4-subsets. There are overall `binom(7)(4)` subsets.

1. iteration: `[a,b,c,d]`
2. iteration: `[e,f,g,a]` (now each element was selected at least once)
3. iteration: `[b,c,d,e]`
4. iteration: `[f,g,a,b]` (now each element was selected at least twice)
5. iteration: `...`

[image: first 21 iterations of my first attempt]

This only works, if `n` is prime. It does not work with `n = 6` and `k = 3`.

---

I need an algorithm to get ALL possible subsets without generating them beforehand (for `binom(30)(15)` we already have over 150 million subsets).

(I want to implement this with javascript, but any suggestion is welcome.)

Comment: You seem to be asking about set cover, i.e. select a subset of the subsets so that all values are covered equally - an NP problem.

Comment: I don't see how this is related to set covering, since I iterate all subsets. The problem is, that I want to iterate them in such a way, that with each iteration each item has in sum roughly the same number of occurrences.

Comment: If you iterate all subsets then every item will have appeared the same number of times.

Comment: I should rephrase that: I do not necessarily iterate over all k subsets. I iterate only up to a certain index that is less than or equal to the number of subsets.

Comment: Exactly, and the problem of finding such a subset that equally favors each item is NP complete.

Comment: Okay, thank you for explaining this. But I still need an algorithm for it, even if it is inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If n = 2k, then there's a simple solution. Enumerate all k-subsets containing 1, following each by its complement.

If n ≠ 2k but k divides n, then I think you need the [construction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25902878/2144669) underlying [Baranyai's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baranyai%27s_theorem) to keep all numbers within one occurrence of each other. This is not an ideal solution, since it requires both a complicated algorithm and keeping the entire list in memory at once.

I have no idea how to do the other cases off hand (though due to the symmetry of the problem, an NP-hardness reduction (for, e.g., given n and k and g, determine whether it's possible to keep the max difference to at most g) seems extremely unlikely to be forthcoming). Perhaps you could describe your fallback requirements.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is efficient but not optimally precise.

There exists an efficient algorithm to unrank combinations, i.e., given n and k and an integer j ∈ {0, ..., (n choose k) − 1}, return the jth combination in lexicographic order.

Compose that algorithm with a format-preserving encryption scheme that randomly permutes {0, ..., (n choose k) − 1} and you get an algorithm that approximately balances the frequency of each element. I think I'd use the FFX mode of AES to get a permutation of {0, ..., m−1} where m is the least power of two not less than n choose k and then do cycle-walking, but someone more knowledgeable than me about crypto might have a better idea.

To control the variance, I'd generalize this algorithm to keep a pool containing a fixed number of combinations, then alternately (1) greedily take the combination from the pool that was the least unfair (2) add the next combination to the pool.